# How to use keyword while sending an sms in mobile connect?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sendsmsactivity

My marketing cloud  org has around 30 business unit and i am new to this org. We have one short code for county US and it is showing 30 of 30 keywords used.
Whenever i am initiating a sms send, i am able to select short code but for keyword i am not able select or create any. My guess is that already 30 keywords assigned are created and used by some other business unit.
I am new to mobile connect and the question might be confusing but if anybody has a clue as to how shud i create keyword then pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Short Code is shared across business units, then indeed, other business units will likely have keywords already created.

You can either raise a support case and ask Support to provide you a list and breakdown as to which business units have the keyword registered, or alternatively if you go through each business unit and check the configuration of MobileConnect then you will find where/who is using each code.

Unfortunately Keywords can't be shared across business units - and this includes Stop words, so likely you could have just 10 business units consuming all 30 keywords simply by having 3 keys in each for :

1) OptIn Keyword
2) Help Word
3) Stop Word

Comment: you just wrote what i was not hoping for. thanks for the explanation and yes the short code is shared across the business unit so i guess i need to access each of the business unit to check. Thanks Again.